# What's wrong with the following Fortran code? (gfortran) DTIO dummy argument at (1) must be an ASSUMED SHAPE ARRAY

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I have the following code:

```
module scheme

  type, abstract :: scheme_object
   contains
     procedure, pass :: generic_scheme_print => print_scheme_object
     generic, public :: write (formatted) => generic_scheme_print
  end type scheme_object

  abstract interface
     subroutine packageable_procedure(  )
       import scheme_object
     end subroutine packageable_procedure
  end interface
contains

  subroutine print_scheme_object(this, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
    class(scheme_object), intent(in) :: this
    integer, intent(in)         :: unit
    character(*), intent(in)    :: iotype
    integer, intent(in)         :: v_list (:)
    integer, intent(out)        :: iostat
    character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg
    iostat = 1
  end subroutine print_scheme_object

  subroutine packaged_cons( )
  end subroutine packaged_cons

  function make_primitive_procedure_object( proc1 ) result( retval )
    class(scheme_object), pointer :: retval
    procedure(packageable_procedure), pointer :: proc1
  end function make_primitive_procedure_object


  subroutine ll_setup_global_environment()
    procedure(packageable_procedure), pointer :: proc1
    class(scheme_object), pointer :: proc_obj_to_pack
    proc1 => packaged_cons
    proc_obj_to_pack => make_primitive_procedure_object( proc1 )
  end subroutine ll_setup_global_environment

end module scheme

program main
end program main
```

This code compiles fine with ifort 19.1.1.217 20200306, runs and does nothing (as expected).

However, compiling it with gfortran fails with a cryptic error message:

```
   16 |   subroutine print_scheme_object(this, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
      |                                                           1
Error: DTIO dummy argument at (1) must be an ASSUMED SHAPE ARRAY
```

Changing the length of the "v_list" declaration to any integer produces two identical mesages:

```
   16 |   subroutine print_scheme_object(this, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
      |                                                           1
Error: DTIO dummy argument at (1) must be an ASSUMED SHAPE ARRAY

   16 |   subroutine print_scheme_object(this, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
      |                                                           1
Error: DTIO dummy argument at (1) must be an ASSUMED SHAPE ARRAY
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: No expert on DTIO, never used it, hence a comment rather than an answer - but from my limited understanding this looks fine to me

Comment: Can this be a compiler bug?

Comment: This is certainly a compiler bug.  Not only is the interface of `generic_scheme_print` correct, but changes to the code elsewhere remove the error message.

Comment: Which gfortran version issues the bug? You can check the bugzilla and try the latest version. If the bug is not present in the bugzilla you should either report it or you can tell us that you are unable to do that and we can try ourselves.

Comment: It is a bug in gfortran.

Comment: A patch has been sent to the fortran@gcc.gnu.org mailing list.

Comment: @evets, do you want to make this an answer? I tested the patch and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this constitutes a proper answer, but...

Your code is correct and exposes a bug in a particular compiler.